# Solving two simultaneous equations in x and y

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, systems-of-equations

During solving a complex numbers question, after comparing the real and imaginary parts, it finally came down to these 2 equations-

$$x^3-3xy^2 = y \quad \text{ and }\quad  y^3-3yx^2= -x.$$

I am unable to solve further as I can't think of any factorisation or manipulation which can solve the above.

Does anyone have any approach which can help solve them?

P.S. The orignal equation was : z^3 = i* conjugate(z)

Comment: Can you also post what your original complex numbers were? I suspect you have a cubic equation of some sort, could you please write it explicitly? Maybe you don't need to do what you are doing, and can possibly solve it directly in the complex numbers???

Comment: The orignal equation was : z^3 = i* conjugate(z)

Comment: WolframAlpha has a fairly simple solution, which doesn't look like  it requires solving a cubic:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-3xy%5E2+%3D+y+and+y%5E3-3yx%5E2%3D+-x

But I can't see how to get there easily.

Comment: You are advised to post that into the body of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$z^3=i\overline{z}$ implies $z^4=i|z|^2$ (multiply both sides by $z$), so $|z|^4=|z|^2$ (take the modulus of both sides). This gives you $|z|=0$ or $|z|=1$.

- If $|z|=0$ then $z=0$
- If $|z|=1$ then solve $z^4=i|z|^2=i$, i.e. your solutions are fourth roots of $i$: $z=\cos\frac{\pi}{8}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{8}$, $z=\cos\frac{5\pi}{8}+i\sin\frac{5\pi}{8}$, $z=\cos\frac{9\pi}{8}+i\sin\frac{9\pi}{8}$, $z=\cos\frac{13\pi}{8}+i\sin\frac{13\pi}{8}$

Of course, as we used implication method to solve the equation, one is advised to check that those are all actual solutions (which they do turn out to be).

Answer (score 3):

From $z^3= i \cdot \bar z$ it follows
$$|z|^3= |z|$$ and therefore you have either $z=0$ or $|z|=1$.
In the latter case $\bar z= z^{-1}$ and the original equation becomes $z^4= i$, which has the following 4 solutions
$$ e^{i \frac \pi 8}, e^{i \frac {5\pi} 8}, e^{i \frac {9\pi} 8}, e^{i \frac {13\pi} 8}. $$

Answer (score 1):

**Direct resolution:**

$x=y=0$ is an obvious solution.

Then $x$ time the first equation plus $y$ times the second give

$$x^4-6x^2y^2+y^4=0,$$

which factors as

$$(x^2-(3-\sqrt8)y^2)(x^2-(3+\sqrt8)y^2)=0$$

then

$$\left(x-\sqrt{3-\sqrt8}\,y\right)\left(x+\sqrt{3-\sqrt8}\,y\right)\left(x-\sqrt{3+\sqrt8}\,y\right)\left(x+\sqrt{3+\sqrt8}\,y\right)=0.$$

Now, plugging $y=ax$ in the first equation,

$$x^3-3x^3a^2=ax$$ gives

$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{a}{1-3a^2}}.$$

As only two among the four $a'$s are positive, this gives us four distinct solutions.

Comment: I couldn't quite understand after x=ay was put?

Comment: @InfiniteCool23: that cubic equation is very simple.